# How to restart mysqld which was started with mysqld_safe?

Tags: mysql

I have `ps`

```
mysql     1562  0.0  0.0 113316  3064 ?        Ss   Sep01   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
mysql     1895  1.8  1.0 3011308 251660 ?      Sl   Sep01 2828:21  \_ /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/main_db/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/main_db/mysql/mysql.sock
```

running in the background.

How to restart it in the same way?

I stopped with

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

then did the following and it hanged:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
201215 04:13:30 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
201215 04:13:30 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /main_db/mysql
```

How to stop it now and restart?

---

This also doesn't work:

```
sudo runuser -l mysql -c 'mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr'
runuser: warning: cannot change directory to /var/lib/mysql: No such file or directory
This account is currently not available.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always kill a process using `kill`, if you know its ID, or using `pkill`, which matches the command (and might be a bit more dangerous, since it might match the wrong process or more than one).  I'd go with:

```
# pgrep -lf mysql
```

(change `mysql` to `mariadb` if running the latter) then check the output to get the `PID` (the first field on the correct process' line) and then kill it using `kill`

```
# kill -TERM <PID>
```

You can check [MySQL's manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/unix-signal-response.html) for other signals and how they affect MySQL's server.

On a different note, I'm not sure killing a database server "in cold blood" is a good idea, as it might leave the databases in weird states. Make sure to use `-TERM` to let it die safely.

I'd try to find out what is causing the hang in the first place, and in fact check if it really is hung.  `mysqld_safe` doesn't fork into the background, so you won't get back to the shell once it is started, and (at least in my case) doesn't react to `^C`, so the behaviour you show is expected.  Opening a different terminal and running `pgrep` and `kill` as above killed the server nicely, as shown on its log:

```
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 201219 16:08:47
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 126817447; transaction id 271335
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-12-19 16:08:47 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
```